# C# correct way to use strategy pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am trying to refactor my code. Currently I have different method names for similar kind of funcitonality as shown below.

```
public interface IReminderService
{
    Task GenerateInviteReminders(string executedBy);
    Task GenerateBookingReminders(string executedBy);
}
```

But want to use something like below. But not sure how to pass parameters in switch case to set the strategy. The interfaces are injected using IOC. Or please let me know the correct way to refactor my code.

```
public interface IReminderStrategy
{
    Task GenerateReminders(string executedBy);
}

public class StrategyA : IReminderStrategy
{
    public StrategyA(IInterfaceA a, IInterface b)
    {}
}

public class StrategyB : IReminderStrategy
{
    public StrategyB(IInterfaceA a, IInterface b)
    {}
}   


public class ExampleService {
    private readonly IInterfaceA _a;
    private readonly IInterfaceB _b;
    public ExampleService(
        IInterfaceA a,
        IInterfaceB b
    ) {}
    switch case(string messageType)
    {
        IReminderStrategy strategy;
        case "A":
            strategy = new StrategyA(?????)
            break;
        case "B":
            strategy = new StrategyB(?????)
            break;          
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to implement the method from the interface in the Strategies A&B first. 
Within which you then start your tasks.

Comment: I think you need to pass "A" and "B" as parameter to the IReminderStrategy interface method. You should check this article https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/aspnetcore-and-the-strategy-pattern

Answer (score 0):

You context class (`ExampleService`) should not be aware that there are different implementations of a particular behavior (strategies). Instead of the context class being responsible for instantiating a strategy, you should pass the strategy as its dependency instead. That way you achieve loose coupling as the instantiation might depend on a lot of factors outside the scope of the context class and it might also be fairly complex. It allows you as well to add more strategies in the future without having to modify `ExampleService`.

```cs
public class ExampleService 
{
    private readonly IReminderStrategy strategy;

    public ExampleService(IReminderStrategy strategy)
    {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }
}
```

The decision on which strategy type to provide should be delegated to the IoC container. Something like

```cs
if (useA)
{
    // bind IReminderStrategy to StrategyA
}
else
{
    // bind IReminderStrategy to StrategyB
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need one more class(ConcreteClass) here to implement interface method and pass your objects(StrategyA or StrategyB) as parameters into new this class object(ConcreteClass) then call the method when required.

```
switch (message)
        {
            case "A":
                concreteObject.SampleMethod(new StrategyA());
                break;
            case "B":
                concreteObject.SampleMethod(new StrategyB());
                break;
            default:                    
                break;
        }
.... 
concreteObject.Execute(inputMessage)

class Concrete
{
    IReminderStrategy _reminderStrategy;
    public void SampleMethod(IReminderStrategy reminderStrategy)
    {
        _reminderStrategy = reminderStrategy
    }

    public void Execute(string message)
    {
        _reminderStrategy.GenerateReminders(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I use strategy or template method patterns frequently since you take the advantage of dynamic dispatch or polymorphism and you mostly get rid of if-else blocks. I mean you put that logic in one place so prevent the if-elses that are scattered to multiple places. For further study you may compare them to higher order functions in functional programming.

```
public interface IReminderStrategy
{
    Task GenerateReminders(string executedBy);
}

public class InviteReminder : IReminderStrategy
{
    private IInterfaceA _a;
    private IInterfaceB _b;
    public InviteReminder(IInterfaceA a, IInterface b){
       _a = a; _b = b;
    }

    public Task GenerateReminders(String executedBy) {
       _a.doSomething;
       _b.doSomething;
       //do invite reminder specific actions here.
    }

}

public class BookingReminder : IReminderStrategy
{
    private IInterfaceA _a;
    private IInterfaceB _b;
    public BookingReminder(IInterfaceA a, IInterface b){
       _a = a; _b = b;
    }

    public Task GenerateReminders(String executedBy) {
       _a.doSomething;
       _b.doSomething;
       //do booking reminder specific actions here.
    }
}   


public static class ReminderFactory {

    //If there will be no DI then remove injects and static and instantiate the object with dependencies.
    @Inject
    private readonly IInterfaceA _a;

    @Inject
    private readonly IInterfaceB _b;

    /* made the class as static so as you said we will be using a DI container.
    public ReminderFactory(IInterfaceA a, IInterfaceB b) {
       _a = a; 
       _b = b;
    }
    */

    public IReminderStrategy getReminder(String messageType) {
       switch case(messageType)
       {
          IReminderStrategy strategy;
          case "invite":
             strategy = new InviteReminder(_a, _b)
             break;
          case "book":
             strategy = new BookingReminder(_a, _b)
             break; 
       }         
    }
}
```

1) instantiate and pass strategy (for pedagogical purposes i.e. to illustrate clearly.)

then in somewhere and one step before in the client:

```
IReminderStrategy reminderStrategy = ReminderFactory.getReminder("invite");
shopService.shop(reminderStrategy);
```

finally in the client:

```
public class ShopService {
   public void shop(IReminderStrategy reminderStrategy) {
      reminderStrategy.GenerateReminders("taha");
   }
}
```

2) or directly:

```
public class ShopService {
   public void shop() {
      //...
      IReminderStrategy reminderStrategy = ReminderFactory.getReminder("invite");
      reminderStrategy.GenerateReminders("taha");
      //...
   }
}
```

and possibly in another service:

```
public class TravelService myService() {
   public void travel() {
      //travel preparation
      IReminderStrategy reminderStrategy = ReminderFactory.getReminder("book");
      reminderStrategy.GenerateReminders("admin");
      //other travel things or maybe do something with the result.;
   }
}
```